# Android ParseFacebookUtils : Login into two different apps backed by same Parse server & database

Tags: android, single-sign-on, facebook-login, parse-server, parsefacebookutils

I have two apps (for ex: A and B) live, backed with the Parse Server(now hosted on Heroku).

Both apps point to the same Server App i.e Same `parse_app_id` and `parse_client_key` and everything working fine except Login with Facebook.

I have Implemented Facebook login with `parsefacebookutils-v4-android` in both apps, but the problem is both apps use separate Facebook app i.e `facebook_app_id` for both apps are different therefore the same Facebook user treat as a separate user in both A &B apps and I want to handle this.  So the Facebook login user of An app no needs to be treated as a new user for B app.

In iOS version of my A and B app, it is working perfectly without any extra implementation but not working for Android.